# How do I proceed from here solving partial differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving a differential problem with boundary conditions and stuck at a point and looking for helps.Here is what I did.

The problem is: Solve the differential equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + u$$
with boundary conditions$$ u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$$

I tried using separating variable method where $$ u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$ and got $$XT'=X''T+1$$ and lost how to proceed.
How do I proceed to solve this?

Comment: A notational remark : It is a partial differential equation (PDE) as opposed to an ordinary differential equation (ODE). So the convention is to use $\partial$ instead of the usual $d$. I have done it on your text.

Comment: It is a variant of "heat Partial Differential equation" :  see equation (4) in {http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/TheHeatEquation.aspx} and what follows.

Comment: its $XT'=X''T+XT$ then separate

Comment: How do I solve it if there is no initial condition given?